# filtering elements in numpy array with a certain minimum frequency

Tags: python, numpy, chi-squared

I have an array of 5000 counts and need to do a chisquare test on it. However the test only works when the expected frequency is >5 for every value. I have found the frequency of each value in the dataset using `collections.Counter(x)` and I can see that there are some values with a frequency of 1 or 2.
Now I would like to remove any value with a frequency<5 from my original dataset x but I don't know how to do this.

Once I have removed these points, I need to create an expected poisson distribution to use in the chisquare test, but once again making sure that the expected frequency is >5. I've made some distributions using `stats.poisson.rvs` but is there a way I can make sure that the frequency is always above 5? Or would it be best to create the distribution, and go through the steps in the first part of my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to filter your array to certain frequency (e.g. `>5`) is (`a` is your original array):

```
#this method assumes array a is consists of integers
a[np.in1d(a, np.where(np.bincount(a)>5)[0])]
```

Another way is:

```
#works for non-integer arrays
values, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
a[np.in1d(a, values[counts>5])]
```

I would guess `bincount` solution is faster.

Comment: When I try this i get 'TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: @niallygee is your array consist of integers? I assumed they are integers based on _I have an array of 5000 counts_. If they are not integers, please use the second proposed solution.

Comment: The counts were not all integers, but this second solution has worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @niallygee Glad it helped.